# Can anyone tell me, Who am I?

Tags: wordplay, letter-sequence

I am 3/8 of PAKISTAN

3/8 of ISTANBUL

2/10 of ANTARCTICA

Who am I?

Comment: For this problem to make sense, shouldn't we assume that the letters in the answer appear *no more* than the given percentage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you *could* be

> 100% of PAKISTAN (**PAK**ISTAN + **IST**ANBUL + **AN**TARCTICA)

or possibly

> the Quebecois profanity *TABARNAC!* (also works with spelling TABARNAK)

Answer (score 7):

> since you just give ratio and no info is given that they must be together, taking 3 letters from Pakistan and Istanbul, 2 letters from anttarctica:

You can be:

> PANTSUIT (**PA**KISTA**N** + I**ST**ANB**U**L + ANTARC**TI**CA)

Comment: this is so good

Answer (score 6):

I'd vote for...

> SATANICA, the album by Behemoth. Aren't all hidden messages about Satan?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

> a PASTABAR? (**PA**KI**S**TAN + IS**TA**N**B**UL + ANT**AR**CTICA)
>
>  see for instance https://www.facebook.com/mypastabar/